# Development on a plugin - How to transfer values

Tags: extension, developer, civix

I have created a new plugin structure using civix.  It has created the elements I wanted in the database.

I have used dogregistry_civicrm_tabset to add a tab to my contacts pages.
I used civix to create a page with a php file and a tpl file.

The question I have is how do I transfer a value to the page php file?  I would like to send it contact ID so I can query the database for the entries for that contact but I'm not sure how to do that or whether it is stored already in a variable I can tap into?

Thanks for your help.
Norm

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I think I figured this bit out by using...

$this->_contactId = CRM_Utils_Request::retrieve(...

and making sure the calling url has cid={$contactId} included.  I'm getting the contactID in the php code, which will allow me to execute the queries and such I need to list out the details.

Norm